# Multiple choice in recursive function

Tags: recursion, math, combinatorics

So we have this task to Print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n.For example, if input array is {1, 2, 3, 4} and r is 2, then output should be {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4} and {3, 4}. (From [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/) )

So in debug mode I've noticed this. And I wonder What magic makes it jump to recursive mark (marked as "HERE 1") and other time to other mark ("HERE 2") as there is no "if" statements or other statements ??

```
 class MainClass {

 static void combinationUtil(int mainArr[], int mainArrSize, int 
 resultLength, int tempArrIndex, int tempArr[], int mainArrIndex){

    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (tempArrIndex == resultLength)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<resultLength; j++)
            System.out.print(tempArr[j]+" ");
        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }

    // When no more elements are there to put in data[]
    if (mainArrIndex >= mainArrSize)
        return;

    // current is included, put next at next location
    tempArr[tempArrIndex] = mainArr[mainArrIndex];

 **//HERE 1**
    combinationUtil(mainArr, mainArrSize, resultLength, tempArrIndex+1, 
    tempArr,mainArrIndex+1);

    // current is excluded, replace it with next
 **//HERE 2**
    combinationUtil(mainArr, mainArrSize, resultLength, tempArrIndex, 
    tempArr, mainArrIndex+1);
}

    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'

    static void printCombination(int mainArr[], int mainArrSize, int resultLength)    {
    int data[]=new int[resultLength];

    combinationUtil(mainArr, mainArrSize, resultLength, 0, data, 0);
}

/*Driver function to check for above function*/
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {50, 51, 52, 53, 54};
    int r = 3;
    int n = arr.length;
    printCombination(arr, n, r);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic - function makes the first recursive call and after returning makes the second recursive call - just like usual function A calls both function B and function C in order